# make multiple columns by matching multiple column's comma separated values of single table

Tags: mysql

I have a table : orders having columns:

```
--------------------------------
id | liquids| strength
--------------------------------
1  | 1,2,3  | 10,12,13
2  | 2,3,4  | 12,13,18
--------------------------------
```

I want output like below:

```
--------------------------------
id | liquids| strength
--------------------------------
1  | 1      | 10
1  | 2      | 12
1  | 3      | 13
2  | 2      | 12
2  | 3      | 13
2  | 4      | 18
```

---

Comment: what are the types of `liduids` and `strength` columns ? Also, have you tried something to resolve the problem ? If yes, show it with the eventual errors you got.

Comment: both datatypes are varchar.

Comment: How did you perform insertion into `strength` column then ?

Comment: Do **not** store comma separated values. Read up on database normalization.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name To be fair, this *might* be an attempt at normalization!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name says, see normalization - but something like the example provided below can be a step towards it. Note that in this example `ints` is a simple table of integers (i) from 0-9, and `my_table` is your table.

```
SELECT id,IF( LENGTH( liquids ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( liquids, ',', '' ) ) + 1 >= i,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(liquids, ',', i), ',', -1),
             ''
) +0 liquid,
IF( LENGTH( strength ) - LENGTH( REPLACE( strength, ',', '' ) ) + 1 >= i,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(strength, ',', i), ',', -1),
             ''
) +0 strength 
FROM my_table,ints HAVING liquid > 0 ;
```

Comment: but why it gives 0,0 entries ??

Answer (score 0):

Seems impossible without a custom procesure. Take a look at this article: http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-stored-procedure-split-delimited-string-into-rows

Your table structure is not optimal in database world. In most cases, you should keep your data already separated to rows. If you want to transform your database, use scripting language. If you want to do it on the fly and keep your data as it is, reconsider transforming. It really helps to operate on your data.